# Linear equation system problem

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following linear equation system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p81mp.jpg)

Question on picture.Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thank you for your reading of [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: The problem statement asks to represent the system of equations as a vector equation (or matrix/vector equation). Have you seen such a representation before?

Comment: Can you read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) before you post?

Comment: You could read for example this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_equation

Comment: İ dont know how to use matjax ? Maybe you guys be more constractive and helpful for new person in this site.  Be inclusive and respectful. Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain. If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

Comment: I want to help you. The wikipedia site that I referred to has quite useful information. Is it helpful for you? Or what is unclear?

Comment: I am not saying to you. Other clevers guys who harass me. Thanks for reply. You are only guy who reply properly.

Comment: No offense but if you're not willing to learn how to ask good questions, then don't expect help from anyone. No one here is obligated to help you. No one is saying that it's bad for you to be confused about something or have questions. But, at the very least, be the one to lead the discussion on something you're confused about.

Comment: To Abhijeet Vats.I am not saying people obligated to help me or some other people. But this place for helping people. Not harassing and insulting people.If you dont have constractive responds you dont have to write offensive comments on me or other people.Please be inclusive and respectful.

Comment: And i thank you Manjoy Das for very helping answer. Wish covid-19 free days for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\ \vec A$= $ \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 0.3 \\
0 & 1 & 6 \\
-2 & -5 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$,  $\ \vec X$= $\ \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\ 
z \\
\end{pmatrix}$, $\ \vec B$=$\ \begin{pmatrix}
-3 \\
5 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
Then $\ \vec A \vec X$= $\ \vec B$ is the required matrix      notation of your system of equations.